# Angular Directive with Venobox Modal Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm currently working on an app which requires the coupling of the Venobox jQuery plugin and AngularJs' Ng-Repeat to iterate through an array.

Plunker for reference http://plnkr.co/edit/YJHMhdosWyupc4Wus8Zh?p=preview

The current directive is as follows.

```
app.directive("venobox", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: false,
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.initVenobox = function(element) {
                var defaultOptions = {
                    framewidth: '400px',        // default: ''
                    frameheight: '300px',       // default: ''
                    border: '10px',             // default: '0'
                    bgcolor: '#5dff5e',         // default: '#fff'
                    titleattr: 'data-title',    // default: 'title'
                    numeratio: true,            // default: false
                    infinigall: true            // default: false
                };
                var customOptions = scope.$eval($(element).attr('data-options'));
                for(var key in customOptions) {
                    defaultOptions[key] = customOptions[key];
                }
                $(element).venobox(defaultOptions);
            }
        }
    };
});


app.directive('venoboxItem', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: false,
        link: function(scope, element) {
          // wait for the last item in the ng-repeat then call init
            if(scope.$last) {
                scope.initVenobox(element.parent());
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Within the app it is called out as;

```
<data-venobox venobox-item="">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" venobox-item="" class="item">
    <a class="venobox" title="{{ item.title }}" data-type="vimeo" ng-href="{{ item.video.url }}">
      <img ng-src="{{ item.thumbnail.img_url }}">
    </a>
  </div
</data-venobox>
```

The directive works as intended when rending static bits of the array, as in items[0].whatever, but when I include any ng statement outside of the anchor I receive GET http://my.site.url/undefined 404 upon clicking the box. The click event designated by Venobox is getting applied to the modal-container instead of the anchor when using ng-repeat.

Any help with debugging the code or an alternative, better solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you could create an example of this via a Codepen, plunker, or jsfiddle? Its still unclear what 'static bits of the array' represent. How about an example of what the `items` variable would look like?

Comment: I was referring to when I would access a portion of the object utilizing the array[index].value method instead of part.value after using ng-repeat to run through the list. Here's the Plunker for it http://plnkr.co/edit/YJHMhdosWyupc4Wus8Zh?p=preview

Comment: Digging deeper into the differences between the two methods of displaying content, it also seems that when I use ng-repeat, the on-click effect is applied to the modal-container instead of the anchor itself.